# wscript.shell in classic asp running htmldoc - no error report but not work

Tags: asp-classic, htmldoc

The following code produces no error as you can see from the output.  The aim is to convert an html file into a pdf file using htmldoc. The html file is produced fine and the pdf is supposed to be saved into the same folder as the pdf but there is no pdf file produced.

The code is running on Windows 2012 IIS 8. The code worked fine on Windows 2003 server without any problem.

The output is:

Starts here

2/2/2014 3:48:08 PM

Passed through

Run sucessfully

2/2/2014 3:48:08 PM

Can anyone help?    Many thanks!

```
CmdeHTMLDOC=chr(34)& exe_path & chr(34) & " --header ... --footer ../  -t pdf  --textfont Arial --fontsize 9  --quiet --left 1.5cm  --right 1.5cm  " & "  --webpage -f "
set wshell=Server.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
wpath4pdf= CmdeHTMLDOC & chr(34)& pdf_path &chr(34)&" "& chr(34)& html_path &chr(34)
'wshell.Run wpath4pdf, SW_SHOWNORMAL,true 
Response.Write("Starts here<br/>") 
on error resume next 
%> 
<pre><%=now()%></pre> 
<% 
wshell.Run wpath4pdf, SW_SHOWNORMAL,true
Response.write "Passed through<br/>" 
if err.number <> 0 then 
   response.write "Error detected: " & err.number & ": " & err.Description & "<br/>" 
   on error goto 0 
   response.end 
end if 
on error goto 0 
Response.write "Run sucessfully<br/>" 
%> 
<pre><%=now()%></pre> 
<%Set wshell=nothing
```

Comment: have you checked the write permission of the folder you're trying to save to?

Comment: Thanks John - the write permissions are good because I can write the html file there prior to my attempt to convert it. I am thinking that my ISP must not have provided permissions to run a shell command, but nevertheless it seems very strange that there is no error.